# PHP, SPL, AccessArray Interface with Iterator Interface

Tags: php, iterator, spl, arrayaccess

I was thinking about AccessArray interface and the Iterator interface and i was thinking can we combine them?, I mean Setting up array with AccessArray and use a foreach loop with the Iterator, If can some one please help me with example if it possible to combine those two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that you are basically asking for `ArrayObject`.

```
class Foo extends ArrayObject
{
  private $data = [];
  public function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct($this->data);
  }
}
```

Comment: `ArrayObject` additional `Serializable`, `Countable` and instead of `Iterator` `IteratorAggregate` and `Traversable`. The OP _maybe_ doesn't want this, but must say: Don't think so either.

Comment: Yeah, it's definitely more than what he explicitly asked for, but I often see people ultimately reimplementing `ArrayObject` because they don't know it exists.

Comment: Thank you Matthew, becouse of you i understand the concept if built-in behavior, thank you again and have a nice day.

Answer (score 2):

```
class Foo implements ArrayAccess, Iterator {
  // Implement interfaces here
}
```

You can implement as many interfaces as you like.